# Disable specific ligatures in CSS

Tags: css, webfonts, ligature

I use a font featuring beautiful ligatures that I activate in CSS [using `font-feature-settings`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings):

```
font-feature-settings: dlig
```

However, I don’t like two of the ligatures (specifically “ch” and “st”) because they don’t just merge letters but add a decoration.

Is there any way, using CSS, to deactivate ligatures just for these specific combinations of letters?

I could not find anything about this on the Internet (so I fear the answer is “no”), but maybe there is a feature in OTF for that, that can be accessed through CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to the headline in question is no.

What I'm seeing, though, is you've enabled "`dlig`" which is "discretionary ligatures". Those are part of the uncommonly-used part of ligatures. -- today, (and I see this question is 5 years old) you'd use [`font-variant-ligatures`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-ligatures) and set it to `normal`. This usually deactivates those uncommon/custom ones. Typically, ch and st are of that uncommon type.
You can use a site like [fontdrop.info](https://fontdrop.info) to load your WOFF version and see what category each ligature belongs to. You might find that ch and st are discretionary but that the others are part of the "normal" or "common" set, and can set the `font-variant-ligatures` appropriately.